# SQL to MDX query conversion

Tags: sql, mdx

So here is the SQL query :

```
select date(actor_creation_date),count(*) from fse_master group by (actor_creation_date) limit 3;
```

So far I have been able to come up with this :

```
with MEMBER [measures].[actor creation date] AS COUNT(([Measures].[actor creation date]))

select  [Measures].[actor creation date] on columns,
order([fse_master].members ,[Measures].[actor creation date],desc)
on rows
from [fse_masters]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not get confused between a "set" and a "measure". Measure is just a numeric/string entity which is *logical* in nature. You can't count something logical in nature. It needs to be physical in nature to be countable. In MDX terms, it needs to be a set. A set of items to be more precise.

```
select date(actor_creation_date),count(*) 
from fse_master 
group by (actor_creation_date) 
limit 3;
```

In your query, `actor_creation_date` is an actually set of things(dates) which are present in the database. It is physical in nature. In RDBMS terms, this is a column. In MDX terms, this needs to be a set.

If you have a date measure, you can't just simply expect to put a count on top of it and expect it to work.

`COUNT([measures].[actor creation date])` transforms to something like 
`COUNT({12345})` which is a count of set which comprises of only one member that is a value. It's output would always be one.

What you need is to run the `COUNT` function on a **set** of dates.

You must be having a Date dimension which will have the `actor creation date` as one of the attribute.

Lets say it looks like below:

```
[Date].[actor creation date].[actor creation date]
```

Now you try to have a calculated member which would hold the count for every date.

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.CountOfDate
AS
COUNT([Date].[actor creation date].[actor creation date].CURRENTMEMBER)
```

`limit 3` suggests that you want the top 3 dates. `HEAD` function in MDX takes care of that.

The final query would be :

```
SELECT HEAD([Date].[actor creation date].[actor creation date].MEMBERS, 3) ON 1,
Measures.CountOfDate ON 0
FROM [fse_masters]
```

**EDIT -** As @whytheq told, my initial attempt was incorrect.

You can try something on the lines of the below:

```
WITH SET ActorCreationDates AS
[Date].[actor creation date].[actor creation date].MEMBERS

MEMBER Measures.CountOfDate
AS
COUNT(EXISTING ActorCreationDates)

SELECT HEAD(ActorCreationDates, 3) ON 1,
Measures.CountOfDate ON 0
FROM [fse_masters]
```

Or, if you need all the records, not just the top 3, then:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ActorCreationDates) ON 1,
Measures.CountOfDate ON 0
FROM [fse_masters]
```

The `EXISTING` clause computes the 'CountOfDate' in the current context, i.e. the particular member on Axis 1.

Comment: sourav - (upped) for your explanation of sets and count - glad _you_ had the patience. I disagree with your `Measures.CountOfDate` as the `.CURRENTMEMBER` will only be a single member if you have `[Date].[actor creation date].[actor creation date].MEMBERS` on an axis - so your measure will always be 1 (you could test this in AdvWrks)

Comment: @whytheq Thank you for pointing that out! Have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I like that additional script - can you add an AdvWrks equivalent please I'd like to play around with it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a measure with a name the same as an existing measure - does this causes an exception?

> with MEMBER [measures].**[actor creation date]** AS
>   COUNT(([Measures].**[actor creation date]**))

I would think for any member, of any hierarchy, there is 1 of each measure for that member so your script will just churn out 1 for each count?

In AdvWrks I did this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[x] AS 
    Count([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[x]
  } ON 0
 ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Subcategory] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It returns this:

[image]

Can a measure get added to your cube for what you require? It will need to contain the relevant relationships and measure type i.e. a count.